# Component of an arbitrary set in a Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

In a Hausdorff space, do there always exist a partition by connected component of an arbitrary set $U$? We know that for each point in Hausdorff-space, there exists always a neighbourhood distinct from each other. However, I am not quite sure, if such neighbourhood is necessarily connected. If yes, we can just can take the smallest neighbourhood around each point as connected component union of all such sets to reconstruct U.

Comment: What about $\mathbb Q$, with the topology induced as a subset of the reals? It is totally disconnected.

Comment: @peterag You are right, what would be the necessary condition for an arbitrary set U allowing a partition by connected component? If I require U to be open, would this problem be fixed?

Comment: I don't know about 'necessary condition' - but you might look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_connected_space. But hold on: maybe somebody will something more intelligent to say on this than I.... And the condition that $U$ be open (in your  comment) probably doesn't help - same counter example as before,  agree?

Comment: Any set consisting of $/Bbb{Q}$ is not open under the usual topology as each open ball contains at least one irrational number, isnt it?

Comment: I meant if you consider the set $X=\mathbb Q$ as 'the' ambient space, albeit with the topology inherited from the reals. Then $X$ is open in $X$, as are the 'intervals' $(a,b)\cap X$, which remain totally disconnected, and form a basis for the topology of $X$. BTW 'quallenjager' is a nice name.